# How to animate single item in LongListSelector?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I am trying to animate item removal from `LongListSelector`. However I have no idea how to pass selected item to `StoryBoard.SetTarget`. I was so far able to pass whole `LongListSelector` so when `SelectionChanged` event is fired everything disappears (I want to animate `Opacity` from 1 to 0). I have custom template for my list.

My code:

```
Storyboard s = new Storyboard();

            DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();
            animation.To = 0;
            animation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.70));

            Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, selector);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(OpacityProperty));

            s.Children.Add(animation);

            s.Begin();

            s.Completed += s_Completed;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access items in a LongListSelector you will need to use a VisualTreeHelper which goes through the "children" of the LongListSelector.

Check out the following link which applies to the ListBox control but works essentially the same for a LongListSelector:

http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/how-to-access-a-control-placed-inside-listbox-itemtemplate-in-wp7

Comment: How do we get the Container since the LongListSelector does not support ItemContainerGenerator ? I am upgrading my code to use LLS instead of ListBox but this little things caused me headaches.